# Which tag is useful to play youtube, amazon and itunes video using single tag?

Tags: html, html5-video

I want to play amazon, youtube and itunes video using single tagcin html.

Suggest me if any easy tag available in html.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `video` tag in html

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 0):

We have semantic tags in HTML 5 for different purposes. You can use `video` tag to embed video in your HTML content like this -

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="PATH_TO_VIDEO_FILE" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

There are several attributes available for video tag -

> - `src` : Source of your video
> - `controls` : Provides control in your video player
> - `loop` : After ending, video will restart automatically
> - `preload` : To preload the video.

You can learn more about the video link here -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

#### Alternatively

You can use `iframe` like this -

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

Comment: But in the ios mobile video not auto play

Comment: In iOS 9, it is not possible to autoplay video, but in iOS 10 the restriction was lifted with some conditions. Learn more about it here - https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: for the ios 9 what we do ?